# Java JNI call to C# COM fails, when COM is registered without codebase option of regasm

Tags: c#, java, java-native-interface, c++-cli

Function calls from Java to C# through JNI-C++/CLI are failing when the C# COM is not registered using regasm with the codebase option. I've built a sample following the instructions in [P2: Calling C# from Java](http://s0ft1.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/p2-calling-c-from-java/) with some changes.

**Numero uno: C#**

Change the C# dll into a COM by creating an interface, `IRunner`, and making the library *assembly COM-visible.*

```
namespace RunnerCOM
{
    public interface IRunner
    {
        String ping();
    }
    public class Runner:IRunner
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        public Runner() { }
        public String ping()
        {
            return "Alive (C#)";
        }
    }
}
```

**Numero due: Java**
No changes made to the Java section.

**Numero tre: C++**

This part was changed to create a new instance of the `RunnerCOM.Runner` class and use that result. Here is a good tutorial on how to call managed code from unmanaged code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Runner.h"
#pragma once
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#import "RunnerCOM.tlb"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Runner_ping(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    RunnerCOM::IRunnerPtr t = RunnerCOM::IRunnerPtr("RunnerCOM.Runner");
    BSTR ping = t->ping();

    _bstr_t temp(ping, true);

    char cap[128];
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<temp.length();i++){
        cap[i] = (char)ping[i];
    }

    return env->NewStringUTF(cap);
}
```

Now to my questions,

1. The code above fails with a _com_error exception, *Class not registered (0x80040154)* unless the *codebase* option is enabled during regsitration of RunnerCOM.dll, with regasm.exe. Why is this? If the code is not ran from JNI, I tested it as an exe, it works fine. The RunnerCOM.dll is simply found in the working directory.
2. Type casting `_bstr_t temp` to `char*` fails. For example, `char *out = (char*) temp;` Similar to the issue above, it works fine when it's built and executed as an exe but crashes the JVM when it's a JNI call.

By the way this is what I used to run it as an executable:

```
int main(){
    RunnerCOM::IRunnerPtr t = RunnerCOM::IRunnerPtr("RunnerCOM.Runner");
    BSTR ping = t->ping();

    _bstr_t temp(ping, false);

    printf(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Codebase creates a Codebase entry in the registry. The Codebase entry specifies the file path for an assembly that is not installed in the global assembly cache, so when you specify the codebase, the system will find the DLL based on the path. If not, it will try to locate the dll in the GAC and current working directory. In JNI, I think the current working directory is not the folder where the DLL is. You can use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find what is the current working directory, also, you can use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out which directories the exe is looking into to find the dll.
2. The code converting _bstr_t to char*, the char* string cap is not ended with '\0', I think this might cause problem in JNI. Uses the _bstr_t operator (char *), you can obtain a null terminated string from the _bstr_t object. Please check the [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

You mentioned C++/CLI, C++/Cli and COM warpper are two different ways to interop with C# code. If you're using C++/CLI as a bridge, you doesn't need to register C# DLL as COM, please see this: [Calling .Net Dlls from Java code without using regasm](http://codefry.blogspot.ca/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html).

If you're using COM, you should call [CoInitialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to init COM first in your code.

Comment: I'm looking for more concrete answers with references. For example, I've made the same assumptions as you have for question 1. It looks for the dll in system32 folder during loading, but the working directory is correctly initialized (just don't know why it doesn't look there). For the second answer, _bstr_t to char* conversion is supposed to work as I described. Thanks for the other points though.